# Why the javascript code not working in laravel blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a social media website, when I tried to make an AJAX request for the following functionality I have found that the javascript is not working, it seems like it does not exist but when I inspect the elements in the browser it exists.

This is my `app.blade.php` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    @auth
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-notification nav-item  dropdown-notifications">
                            <a class="nav-link nav-link-label" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                                <span
                                    class="badge badge-pill badge-default badge-danger badge-default badge-up badge-glow   notif-count"
                                    data-count="9">9</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-media dropdown-menu-right">
                                <li class="dropdown-menu-header">
                                    <h6 class="dropdown-header m-0 text-center">
                                        <span class="grey darken-2 text-center"> الرسائل</span>
                                    </h6>
                                </li>
                                <li class="scrollable-container ps-container ps-active-y media-list w-100">
                                    <a href="">
                                        <div class="media">
                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                <h6 class="media-heading text-right ">عنوان الاشعار </h6>
                                                <p class="notification-text font-small-3 text-muted text-right"> نص
                                                    الاشعار</p>
                                                <small style="direction: ltr;">
                                                    <p class=" text-muted text-right" style="direction: ltr;">
                                                        20-05-2020 - 06:00 pm
                                                    </p>
                                                    <br>

                                                </small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>

                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-menu-footer"><a class="dropdown-item text-muted text-center" href="">
                                        جميع الاشعارات </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endauth
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @guest
                        @if (Route::has('login'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @else
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                    onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endguest
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>

    @stack('footer-js')
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my view file which extends `app.blade.php` file:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container emp-profile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-img">
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog"
                        alt="" />
                    <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        Change Photo
                        <input type="file" name="file" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="profile-head w-100">
                    <div class="d-flex  justify-content-between">
                        <div class="">
                            <h5>{{ $user->name }}</h5>
                            <h6>{{ $user->profile->job ? $user->profile->job : '"No job yet"' }}</h6>
                        </div>
                        @auth
                            @if (Auth::user()->id === $user->id)
                                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                                    <a href="{{ route('profile.edit', ['username' => $user->username]) }}"
                                        class="btn btn-dark">Edit Profile</a>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        @endauth
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <p>{{ $user->profile->descripyion ? $user->profile->descripyion : '"No Description yet"' }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab"
                                aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            @auth
                @if (Auth::user()->id != $user->id)
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <form id="follows-form" action="{{ route('follow') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="submitBtn" name="follow">Follow</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                @endif
            @endauth

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="profile-work">
                    <p>WORK LINK</p>
                    <a href="">Website Link</a><br />
                    <a href="">Bootsnipp Profile</a><br />
                    <a href="">Bootply Profile</a>
                    <p>SKILLS</p>
                    <a href="">Web Designer</a><br />
                    <a href="">Web Developer</a><br />
                    <a href="">WordPress</a><br />
                    <a href="">WooCommerce</a><br />
                    <a href="">PHP, .Net</a><br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>User Id</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>{{ $user->username }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>{{ $user->email }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Profession</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>{{ $user->profile->job ? $user->profile->job : '"No job yet"' }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection

@push('footer-js')
    <script>
        console.log('it\'s working');
        const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submitBtn');
        submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        function follow() {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', {{ route('follow', ['profile_id' => $user->id]) }});
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState > 3 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    success(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.send({
                '_token': {{ csrf_token() }}
            });
            return xhr;
        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

I can't figure out why, I hope anyone help me.

and here is the console:
[image]

Comment: It seems your code is correct. Can you please see your browser's console and check if there is any javascript error ? If you can attach an image of it throwing the error, that would be better.

Comment: You say you are trying to make an AJAX call to an endpoint, and the JavaScript  isn’t working. Do you expect the Ajax call to interpret the result beyond text?

Comment: @matiaslauriti  First thanks for your time, and I have edited the post with the console errors as you wanted.

Comment: Try change `'_token': {{ csrf_token() }}` to `'_token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"`.

Comment: Based on the screenshot above there are syntax error in the javascript. Could you please click on the red text in the browser console (`deon86:215`)? It will show you which line is on the script that has problem. Please share also the image of it.

Comment: Thanks All it has been solved when i changed this line `xhr.open('POST', {{ route('follow', ['profile_id' => $user->id]) }});`to `xhr.open('POST', "{{ route('follow', ['profile_id' => $user->id]) }}");`

Comment: @DharmaSaputra your comment helped me to solve it thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to help.